# Comprehensive list of valid css attributes for every html tag in html4 and/or html5

Tags: html, css, tags, styles

I am looking for a comprehensive list of valid css attributes for every html tag in html4 and/or html5, preferrably both.

Posting this as an answer would be too long; I am only looking for a referral. I searched, but could not find such a list. Does it exist?

HTMLDog provides this information here and there, for example:

> IE will only apply inline-block to elements that are traditionally inline such as span or a but not p or div. Loopy.

It has been commented that all css properties are valid for all html elements, but certainly something like border-collapse is not valid for a `<p>`.

It has also been noted that some css properties may contradict or require one another. That is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/

Comment: You might be interested in [overapi.com](http://overapi.com)

Comment: @Naveen — That's out of date.

Comment: *It has been commented that all css properties are valid for all html elements, but certainly something like border-collapse is not valid for a `<p>`.* — Completely valid, it just only applies if the `<p>` is set to `display: table` (or `inline-table`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CSS **properties** are valid for all elements, so a list that relates properties to elements wouldn't make much sense.

Limits on which CSS properties apply to a given element are based on the values given to other properties (e.g. `left` only applies to elements that are not `position: static`), not the element type.

Comment: I have to disagree with "All CSS properties are valid for all elements". I will update the question with an example.

Comment: So, by specification, the browser should never discard a css property because of the type of '<tag>' to which it applies? I.e. css properties are applied considering ONLY the values of other applied properties? Clearly this is not the case in many versions of IE, as per my example from HTMLDog.

Comment: Yes. That's a (now fixed) bug in Internet Explorer.